# Better way in SQL to fetch most recent customer record?

Tags: sql, hiveql, impala

Imagine we have two tables: customers and purchases.
Purchases has a customerID, purchaseDateTime, etc.

What is the best way to select the most recent purchase for all customers in hive or impala SQL?

I've seen this query:

```
With recent as (
    select customerID, max(purchaseDateTime)     as dt
    from purchases group by customerID
)
Select *
from customer c
join recent r
    on c.customerID = r.customerID
join purchases p
    on r.customerId = p.customerid and
       p.purchaseDateTime = dt
```

Seems like that's not as efficient as it could be...

Comment: On what basis do you decide that it's not as efficient as it could be?

Comment: The sample sql is not complete?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `row_number()`:

```
Select c.*, p.*
from customer c join
     (select p.*,
             row_number() over (partition by p.customerid order by p.purchaseDateTime desc) as seqnum
      from purchases p
     ) p
     on c.customerId = p.customerid and p.purchaseDateTime = dt
where seqnum = 1;
```

`row_number()` is ANSI standard functionality, so it is standard SQL.  In general, it should be faster than doing an explicit `group by` and `join`.

One difference is that -- in the event of ties -- this returns one row.  Your query will return multiple rows.  If you want that behavior, change the `row_number()` to `rank()`.